# Opening an iframe source in a new tab if it tries to redirect the user

Tags: javascript, redirect, onunload

It's a known fact that a lot of websites use javascript codes to prevent from browsing them using iframes. I would like then my iframe to behave like this: if the site doesn't have such a code and isn't trying to redirect the user, its content should be shown in the iframe. But if it's trying to redirect, it should be opened in a new tab (just like links with target="_blank"). Is it possible to use onUnload or any other techniques to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance,
Michael.

Comment: May I ask why? Won't the frame buster of the inlying page have the same effect without you having to do anything?

Comment: @Pekka It will replace the framing page, won't it?

Comment: @bzlm ah, now I see the difference. You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This will be extremely tough and complex and kludgy to achieve, if it's possible at all. It would require to predict the target site's behaviour before navigating to the link.</strike>  On second thought, this may in fact be possible using the `onbeforeunload` event but I expect a lot of trouble with pop-up blockers and the like.

I am assuming you have external links, and would like to show some "return to original site" bar in order to not lose visitors.

What I would do as a simple workaround is open the site in a new `target="_blank"` window in both cases, and have your "return to site" link close the window using `window.close()`.

Comment: Yeah, I think that could be ok, but where should the "return to site" bar be visible? - in the new target="_blank" window? If so, how to do it? I know how to open a new window and how to write to it using document.write but I don't know how to combine opening that external site and writing to its source. Should I appendChild to its body with position: 'absolute' and put it on top of the site? I would appreciate some ideas.