# Opening external websites with a top bar containing "return to site" link

Tags: javascript, user-interface, return

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3952848/623518) shows how to open external sites in a new window and provide a "return to site" link which would call the `windows.close()` function. The problem is, that I don't know how to do such a "top bar" or something else containing the link on the site I open. Should I open the external site and write to its source? I know that for example sites providing proxies use such top structures. But how do they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here... these are the top two suggestions I have.

**Option 1**, a kind of frame

You essentially load up a page that contains your header, and a big iframe that contains the other site. This is really easy to do, but if they have a "framebuster" script, it might get rid of your header when the page loads.

**Option 2**, server side proxy

Another option would be to get their HTML using a server side language, and modify it to include your top bar... it's a lot more work, but it will prevent framebusters from breaking out of your top bar.

Comment: I'm afraid that the first option would have the same effect as my original idea (loading external sites into an iframe) - right? As for the second one, it would be cool to have it already written - if there's nothing like that ready in the Internet, I think that the amount of work would surpass the result. Do you know about any scripts that could do it?

Comment: @kremuwa - what server-side language would you want it in?